# RestSharp Execute works very slow

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, restsharp, webhttpbinding

Is it normal situation that calling `Execute` on 9000 custom object from database take circa 10 sec ?

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:8732/carservice");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.Resource = "GetCarList";
var response = client.Execute<List<Car>>(request);
```

and method working on ms sql:

```
public List<Car> GetCarList()
{
   using (var context = new CarEntities(DbAccess.connectionString))
   {
       return context.Car.Include("Owner").Include("Place").Include("Model").ToList<Car>();
   }
}
```

and service:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
List<Car> GetCarList();
```

Comment: What takes 10 seconds - getting the objects from the database or transferring them over the wire? For the first I would be greatly surprised unless you are running on some prehistoric hardware, for the second it's more realistic -> serializing such large volume and sending it over the wire could take significant amount of time. You might consider implementing pagination on the service to improve performance.

Comment: @Saint Please share your solution, if you had resolved it.